# Installing MySql 8.0.22 Shows options Grayed out when installing

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2016

I have Windows Server 2016 Datacenter.

I need to install MySqL 8.0.22 and the options are all greyed out, even when I attempt the non web installer ??

Any ideas why this might be happening ??

[install image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPSaC.png)

[install image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRhML.png)

Comment: Does this machine have a working internet connection?

Comment: yes it does, I just downloaded it from the internet !

Comment: I have seen this, when the CE-Installer is not able to reach it's backend. Is there any proxy-, security- or firewall solution between you and the internet?

Comment: potentially, ill ask Admin, thanks for the heads up @bjoster :)